# Displaying the first, second, and third posts from a category in separate slides

Tags: loop

I've searched around and I haven't been able to find a solution for exactly what I'm trying to do.

I have [this basic JavaScript slider from w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow) that displays one slide at a time. I'm trying to get each slide to display a different post from a specific category from the loop. Slide #1 should contain the most recent post, slide #2 should contain the second, and slide #3 should contain the third.

This is what I have right now, but it only displays the first post in each of the slides:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <?php
            query_posts("current_post=0&showposts=1&cat=1"); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
                </a>
            <div class="text"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <?php endwhile; else : ?>

                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                <<?php query_posts("current_post=1&showposts=1&cat=1"); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
                </a>
            <div class="text"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <?php endwhile; else : ?>

                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                <<?php query_posts("current_post=2&showposts=1&cat=1"); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
                </a>
            <div class="text"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <?php endwhile; else : ?>

                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

I'd like to accomplish this without a plugin, so my client can just tick the "Featured" category and have the post show up there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of query_posts. You also don't need a separate query to loop through for each one. Just use a WP_Query for the Featured category, limit it to 3 posts, and you should be good to go. It's not necessarily optimized but I cobbled it together with your code sample.

This should get you started:

```
<?php
    $per_page = 3;
    $slideshow_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'cat' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    ) );

    if( $slideshow_query->have_posts() ){
        echo '<div class="slideshow-container">';
            while ( $slideshow_query->have_posts() ) {
                $slideshow_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext"><?= $slideshow_query->current_post + 1; ?> / <?= $per_page ?></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="text"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>';
        </div>
    <?php } else {
        _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
    }
?>
```

Update: with a recent edit it should be noted that

```
<?= $slideshow_query->current_post + 1; ?> / <?= $per_page ?>
```

is **functionally equivalent** to

```
<?php echo $slideshow_query->current_post + 1; ?> / <?php echo $per_page ?>
```

`<?=` is known as the [Short Echo Tag](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+short+echo+tag)

Comment: No sweat, my pleasure!

Comment: May I suggest adding the clause of "how to avoid duplicate" posts? I feel as if this is a huge drawback on UX that many people forget about.

Comment: @jonathan guerin - I'm afraid I don't quite get what you're suggesting

Comment: @Xhynk I wrote about exactly this "popular" issue: https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4483/how-can-we-add-tips-that-offer-a-great-advantage-to-the-answers-we-give-when-th

Comment: Duplicate posts aren't an inherent issue with proper WordPress queries though, otherwise it would be a core Trac issue. The problem here wasn't that OP was having duplicate posts, his code was inherently flawed attempting to run three separate queries offset by one.

Comment: I've been a WP Dev for almost a decade and don't think duplicate posts are a huge issue in most modern themes and plugins, unless the code is flawed. As a matter of fact I've seen more people WANTING duplicate posts in a single query this week than wanting them removed haha